# Rails / Postgres: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, macos

i could not get postgres-gem to run.

macOS 10.15.4
Postgres-App 2.3.5 (https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html)
PostgreSQL -v12
Rails-6.0.2
gem 'pg' v1.2.3

then, i did:
`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/pg_config`
and
`bundle install`

and i'm getting this:

```
Fetching pg 1.2.3 (was 1.1.4)
Installing pg 1.2.3 (was 1.1.4) with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200615-30711-d59mnj.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for PQsslAttribute()... yes
checking for PQresultVerboseErrorMessage()... yes
checking for PQencryptPasswordConn()... yes
checking for PQresultMemorySize()... yes
checking for timegm()... yes
checking for rb_gc_adjust_memory_usage()... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
compiling pg_coder.c
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:975:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:971:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:976:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_connection.c
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:975:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:971:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:976:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
pg_copy_coder.c:534:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                input_len = end_ptr - start_ptr;
                          ~ ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_record_coder.c
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:975:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:971:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:976:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~

...

1 warning generated.
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.2/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.5/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.2/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.5/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.2/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.5/lib'

current directory: /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.31/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: *** [.sitearchdir.time] Error 1

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.5.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

sorry - the whole error-message is much longer, but Stackoverflow did not allow me to paste it in, because it says, i pasted too much code inside the message

In Gemfile:
  pg

previous i did the same with version 1.1.4, same result

what to do?

thanks,
chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it works:
`gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=<path to pg_config>` helped

see: [gem-description](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg#how-to-install-)

don't know what the above error was

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues and this fixed it for me

`gem install pg -v '0.18.2' -- with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`